# Increase Android emulator response time on general/app operation

Tags: android, android-emulator, response-time

Due to some project, I need to work on Galaxy Tab Emulator on my machine. I find its response rate very slow, specially while operating it generally and also on operating my application.

Is there some way I can increase that!! Some virtual primary memory or kind of thing!

Any response is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not tried this already , Increase the RAM size when you are creating a new Virtual device from Android SDK and AVD manager. It might help.